# How do I write multiple times to an http stream to a browser and have each write evaluated as it comes in?

Tags: go

I have an http server that needs to write multiple times to the browser, executing as the lines are written.

I have tasks that occur in between writes that also depend on the contents of the writes (this is a debug tool) so I would likely write chunks from for loop using `w.Write()`

```golang
func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "text/html")
    w.WriteHeader(200)

    w.Write([]byte("<script>performance.mark('start')</script>"))

    time.Sleep(time.Second)

    w.Write([]byte("<script>performance.mark('end')</script>"))
    w.Write([]byte("<script>performance.measure('Time between', 'start', 'end')</script>"))
}
```

I am expecting the performance measurement to be ~1 second as the start mark was written to the browser 1 second before the end mark however the browser renders only once it has received the entire response.

EDIT: It seems that the Go standard library `http.ResponseWriter` does not include the ability to flush the outgoing response however the underlying struct has a `.Flush()` method.

Changing the code to this works but is not the best:

```golang
func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var wf = w.(interface{ Flush() }) // <-- This

    w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "text/html")
    w.WriteHeader(200)

    w.Write([]byte("<script>performance.mark('start')</script>"))

    wf.Flush()  // <-- And this
    time.Sleep(time.Second)

    w.Write([]byte("<script>performance.mark('end')</script>"))
    w.Write([]byte("<script>performance.measure('Time between', 'start', 'end')</script>"))
}
```

Comment: Use server-sent events? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events.

Comment: Use [ResponseControllerr.Flush](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ResponseController.Flush).

Answer (score 0):

just in case you consider using the Gin web framework [doc](https://gin-gonic.com/docs/), I'll provide you an example on how to achieve this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "time"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func Demo(c *gin.Context) {
    // better to use c.HTML() method
    c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
    c.Writer.Write([]byte("Hello"))
    c.Writer.Write([]byte("<script>performance.mark('start')</script>"))

    c.Writer.Flush()
    time.Sleep(time.Second)

    c.Writer.Write([]byte("<script>performance.mark('end')</script>"))
    c.Writer.Write([]byte("<script>performance.measure('Time between', 'start', 'end')</script>"))
}

func main() {
    gin.SetMode(gin.DebugMode)
    r := gin.Default()

    r.GET("/demo", Demo)

    r.Run(":8000")
}
```

Two small things to consider. The first is that the Flush functionality is provided out-of-the-box by the method `c.Writer.Flush`.
Then, as your example is trivial it's fine to write the HTML tags with the `.Write` method. In a real-life scenario maybe, it's better to use the method `c.HTML()` that allows you to use the HTML templates feature.

Hope this provides you with insights about it, thanks!